# TinyMCE custom button VUE

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I can't add custom button with other toolbars

This code work

```
tinyMCE.init({
  selector: '#d1',
  toolbar:'customButton',
  setup(editor) {
    editor.addButton('customButton', {
      text: 'My button',
      icon: false,
      onclick() {
        editor.insertContent("&nbsp;<b>It's my button!</b>&nbsp;")
      },
    })
  },
})
```

But, if i add one more toolbar, it didn't work, why?

```
toolbar: 'forecolor backcolor' + 
         'customInsertButton',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use multiple toolbars in TinyMCE you can use either:

toolbar array: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/TBhaab

```
  toolbar: ['myCustomToolbarButton','forecolor backcolor'],
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#usingmultipletoolbars

toolbar(n): https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/VBhaab

```
  toolbar1: 'myCustomToolbarButton',
  toolbar2: 'forecolor backcolor',
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbarn

Note, you are showing TinyMCE 4 button syntax. If you are using TinyMCE 5 (5.7.1 is the current version) the API for creating custom buttons has changed:

TinyMCE 4 version: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/QBhaab

TinyMCE 5 version: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/SBhaab

```
editor.ui.registry.addButton('myCustomToolbarButton', {
  text: 'My Button',
    onAction: function () {
      editor.insertContent("&nbsp;<b>It's my button!</b>&nbsp;")
    }
 });
```

More info: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/toolbarbuttons/#howtocreatecustomtoolbarbuttons

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much a TinyMCE issue and is more so a JavaScript issue. The problem is with your concatenation logic in:

```
toolbar: 'forecolor backcolor' + 
         'customInsertButton',
```

This will end up becoming `toolbar: 'forecolor backcolorcustomInsertButton'` which as you can see is missing a space/separator between `backcolor` and `customInsertButton`. So to solve that, just make sure to add a space, such as:

```
toolbar: 'forecolor backcolor ' + 
         'customInsertButton',
```